# t-test vs mixed anova analysis

Tags: anova, mixed-model, t-test

I am measuring the effect of fatigue in human movement.
I measure a gait parameter before and after fatigue.
I have tested 60 subjects.
I have 5 measurements of the same parameter before and after fatigue.
I measure 5 times because humans have a variability.

Which of these options would be better for my analysis?

1. Calculate the mean of the 5 measurements, and apply a paired t-test. But this implies that I have only 60x2 samples. One before fatigue, one after fatigue.
2. ANOVA mixed model. The fixed factor is fatigue (No-Yes). And the random factor is the subject.

I think that I should choose the ANOVA. With the ANOVA I have 5x60x2 samples. And more samples increase the power of the test. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use ANOVA mixed model. As far as I know, there are two main reasons for using it. First, by having more data points, the power of the analysis increases. Second, you can also take into account random variability due to subjects and measurements.